# Magento 1.9 Add to Cart very slow

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I have recently upgraded the Magento from 1.6.2 to 1.9.2 and I found the cart page is too slow. Not only when I add product to cart ,but also when i just load the cart page . I did confirm that the site is using the default cartcontroller .
Here is the profiler report.

```
mage::dispatch::routers_match                           2.636556    1   0   0.00 KB
mage::dispatch::controller::action::checkout_cart_index 2.516693    1   0   0.00 KB
Mage_Checkout_CartController::indexActioncart_display   0.560941
```

I also did check with the innodb_buffer_pool_size  and its also setup correctly as per the requirement.

Can anyone help me to figure out the speed issue on cart page? All other pages are running smooth compare to this cart page.

Comment: I little more info would be great. Are you using a caching backend, e.g. varnish? Upgrading from 1.6.2 to 1.9 is quite a step so there are multiple issues that you might run into.

Comment: Well, I am using only default community version cache. This site is having 10k  categories and 10k products with only few custom and third party modules. There is no big customization on cart functionality. 
THanks